# Correct way to parse large numbers of interlaced parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am using Python's argparse to parse the command line arguments and I need to parse a lot of arguments like so

```
laptop-inventory.sh \
--make Toshiba \
--model A50 \
--north-american-units \
    --mac AA:BB:CC:DD:E1 \
    --sn 1234567890 \
    --mac AA:BB:CC:DD:E2 \
    --sn 1234567891 \
    ...
    --mac AA:BB:CC:DD:99 \
    --sn 1234562390 \
--european-units \
    --mac AA:BB:CC:DD:E1 \
    --sn 1234567890 \
    --mac AA:BB:CC:DD:E2 \
    --sn 1234567891 \
    ...
    --mac AA:BB:CC:DD:99 \
    --sn 1234562390 \
```

**Question:** Is it possible to read a section of the arguments sequentially into their own variable, for example to get it into

```
args = parser.parse_args()

args.north_america.mac... #North America MAC addresses
args.north_america.sn... #North America serial numbers
args.europe.mac... #Europe MAC addresses
args.europe.sn... #Europe  serial numbers
```

If not possible, I can change the order and the permutations, but I'd rather not having something impossible to read like so as I deal with thousands of arguments

```
laptop-inventory.sh \
--make Toshiba \
--model A50 \
--north-american-unit-mac-addresses "AA:BB:CC:DD:E1,AA:BB:CC:DD:E2...AA:BB:CC:DD:99"
--north-american-unit-sn "1234562390 ,1234562390 ...1234562390 "
--european-unit-mac-addresses "AA:BB:CC:DD:E1,AA:BB:CC:DD:E2...AA:BB:CC:DD:99"
--european-unit-sn "1234562390 ,1234562390 ...1234562390 "
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: btw, I did look into using the subparser feature, but I think that is for different branches (eg. either `git add -A` or `git push origin master`), it's not for different sections

Comment: @droid_31, sorry, I reworded it better

Comment: possible?  maybe.  fun or clear, probably not.

Comment: With large amounts of data like this, it would be better to read from a file, which the user has a chance to edit and correct before submitting.  Something like a `config` file.